# How to edit items in a Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

i have a gridview control and i bind some data from DB in to it.My problem is i have a price fiekd in the gridview,i bind price into it but i am getting price in this format(eg:10.0000).
How can i set it to (10.00) after binding the grid.

The  gridview  is

```
            <asp:GridView ID="gvTest" Width="600px" runat="server" onrowdeleting="gvConfigItem_RowDeleting" onrowediting="gvConfigItem_RowEditing">
               <Columns>
                  <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-CssClass="AdminGridHeaderNew" ItemStyle-Font-Size="12px"
                        DataField="Totalprice" HeaderText="Total Price" />
             </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
```

my server side code is

```
            gvTest.DataSource=ds;
            gvTest.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set DataFormatString for specific column as per URL--> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DataFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) proeprty:

```
DataFormatString="{0:00.00}"
```

or

```
DataFormatString="{0:C}"
```